# Specific programming text editor for simple open/close editing

Tags: text-editor

I'm looking for very specific text editor:

- Closes on ESC, no project management or tabs
- Syntax highlighting - preferably with color themes (e.g. can apply different color themes without changing C# coloring definition) or, at least, can load/save themes; support for C/C#/XML/HTML/JavaScript/etc - common MS/.NET world - out of box
- Configurable keys, or: Shift-Tab shifts blocks
- XML/HTML auto-completion support - well, optional

I use synplus plugin for Total Commander currently, but it has few drawbacks (e.g. crashes sometimes ;-), no auto-completion, etc).

Basically I want **fast** Visual-Studio-like editor that I open, do edits, and then close using ESC. I remember I tried Notepad++, etc - most of them open files in tabs, don't close on ESC... - that is, behave like IDE.

At least I've just downloaded Notepad++, it doesn't close on ESC even if I setup keybindings to do so.

Autocompletion is optional (though it is to be simple as just tags completion), what I really look for is closing on ESC, not getting in the way with all the tabs and IDE-like, and good coloring. Plus shift-tab is must have for blocks manipulation.

Update: any open-source one that I can easily tweak to close on ESC? ;-) Seems like ESC (and reasonable color highlighting) is the core requirement. I've just tried many editors - Programmer's Notepad, E, Crimson, etc - I can't set any of them to close on ESC. Any external tool to close selected program on ESC? ;-)

UPDATE: Hm, found an awesome utility for my latest thought: http://www.autohotkey.com. Easy to setup to close any window on ESC (as well as many other tricks). Seems like the most tough requirements is gone - I can use ANY text editor ;-)

Comment: Auto-complete and "not behaving like an IDE" are two things that you're probably going to have a hard time finding in the same piece of software.

Comment: Well, this autocompletion is not about intellisense and sources parsing, what I need is rather simple <div> => </div> closing tag completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I close this because I've found a fix for the main issue with ESC key: http://www.autohotkey.com. Here's a sample script that do the trick for e text editor:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
#IfWinActive ahk_class wxWindowClassNR
Esc::WinClose, A
return
```

Now I'm free to choose from wide range of editors.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Emacs 23's new server functionality to make it start fast, and then configuring it to use whatever key bindings you like is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Notepad2. I like it for the same reasons - close on Escape and syntax highlighting. Very light and fast to start.

Comment: Hm, one of the rare editors that do not have tabbed interface... which is good.

Comment: Yep, I prefer the same. Plus it has syntax highlighting (forgot to mention that).

Answer (score 0):

vim?

Sure, it doesn't use esc to quit, but :wq is pretty quick.

Comment: "Closes on ESC" was a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Given you've got rid of the ESC issue I'd suggest taking a look at [jedit](http://www.jedit.org/).  It's fairly lightweight (well, compared to a full IDE), nicely configurable and runs on any OS.  Generally one of the first things I install on any box I'm going to be working on because I know I'll always have a familiar environment.

Comment: Hey, I like it, very nice! - http://www.jedit.org/index.php?page=screenshot&image=25 ;-)

Comment: Does it support ClearType at all?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of tweaking the [Zeus editor](http://www.zeusedit.com) can be configure to behave this way.

To get the editor to close on *ESC* the keyboard mapping will need to be edited and the *ESC* key rebound to the *FileExit* function.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Notepad++ (6.4.5) does let you close files using Esc.  To do this you have to set Esc as the Exit key (Number 19) by using Settings | Shortcut Mapper.